# Formatting is sporadic in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: perl

In attempting to create a spreadsheet using cell properties previously defined, I'm having issues where the cell formatting is only sporadically being written in the cells.  The values are there, but the font color, etc. is not always there.

Here's my code:

```
$result_file = $toxls . ".excel_props.xls";
$property_file = "properties.txt";
open (PROP, ">$property_file");

my $parser          = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook_parse  = $parser->parse( $toxls );

my $worksheet_parse = $workbook_parse->Worksheet( $totab );
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_parse->col_range();
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_parse->row_range();

my $workbook   = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( $result_file );
my $worksheet  = $workbook->addworksheet( $totab );
my %bkgd_color = ();

$worksheet->set_column('A:A', 12);
$worksheet->set_column('C:C', 15);
$worksheet->set_column('D:D', 30);
$worksheet->set_column('E:E', 30);
$worksheet->set_column('F:F', 35);
$worksheet->set_column('G:G', 40);
$worksheet->set_column('I:I', 40);

for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

        # Return the cell object at $row and $col

        my $cell = $worksheet_parse->get_cell( $row, $col );
        next unless $cell;

        my $value     = $cell->value();
        my $format    = $cell->get_format();

        my $pattern   = $format->{Fill}->[0];         
        my $color1    = $format->{Fill}->[1];
        my $color2    = $format->{Fill}->[2];

        my $font      = $format->{Font};
        my $fontcolor = $font->{Color};

        ## Change value if font color = black
        if ($fontcolor eq '32767') {
            $fontcolor = "8";
        }

        my $wrap      = $format->{Wrap};
        my $bold      = $font->{Bold};

        print PROP "\nRow, Col = ($row, $col)\n";
        print PROP "Pattern    = $pattern\n";
        print PROP "Value      = $value\n";
        print PROP "Fill       = $pattern $color1 $color2\n";
        print PROP "Wrap       = $wrap\n";
        print PROP "Font       = $fontcolor\n";
        print PROP "Bold       = $bold\n";

        if (index($value,"B\=baseline") > -1 || index($value,"B\=Baseline") > -1) { 
           $worksheet->set_row($row, 150); 
        }

        if ($pattern == 1 ){

          if ( ! exists $bkgd_color{$color1} ){

             $bkgd_color{$color1}    =  $workbook->add_format(
                                           pattern  => $pattern,
                                           bg_color => $color1,
                                           align => 'left',
                                           valign => 'top',
                                           text_wrap => $wrap,
                                           border   => 1,
                                           color  => $fontcolor,
                                           bold    => $bold
                                     );
             print PROP "Print segment = not exist bkgd_color\n";

          }

          $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value, $bkgd_color{$color1});

        } else {

          $format = $workbook->add_format();
          $format->set_pattern($pattern);
          $format->set_align('left');
          $format->set_valign('top');
          $format->set_bg_color($color2);
          $format->set_fg_color($color1);
          $format->set_color($fontcolor);
          $format->set_text_wrap($wrap);
          $format->set_border();
          $format->set_bold($bold); 

          print PROP "Fontcolor  = $fontcolor\n";

          $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value, $format);

       }        
    }  
}
```

The properties.txt file shows what I expect when I parse the $toxls spreadsheet, which I'm using to test with.  Yet, it doesn't always produce the formatting (font color, Align, and AlignH) that is being saved from the parse, when I write back out to the $result_file.  Any ideas?

The properties.txt file looks good:

```
Row, Col = (2, 3)
Pattern    = 1
Value      = Password Requirements
Fill       = 1 22 31
Wrap       = 1
Font       = 10  <-- red text
Bold       = 1

Row, Col = (3, 3)
Pattern    = 1
Value      = Logging 
Fill       = 1 22 31
Wrap       = 1
Font       = 12   <--- blue text
Bold       = 0

Row, Col = (4, 3)
Pattern    = 0
Value      = Logging 
Fill       = 0 64 65
Wrap       = 1
Font       = 12
Bold       = 0
Fontcolor  = 12

Row, Col = (5, 3)
Pattern    = 1
Value      = AntiVirus
Fill       = 1 22 31
Wrap       = 1
Font       = 8  <-- black text 
Bold       = 0
```

My goal is simply to read in an existing spreadsheet, then create a new one with the exception of altering the font color or fill color on some cells.  I tried this snippet, and it even missed formatting on many of the cells:

```
for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

       # Return the cell object at $row and $col

       my $cell = $worksheet_parse->get_cell( $row, $col );
       next unless $cell;

       my $value     = $cell->value();
       my $format    = $cell->get_format();

       $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value, $format);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get warnings when you put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in and run it?

Comment: Yes, it returned only expected explicit package name warnings for some of the variables that I hadn't declared my $variable.  No other errors or warnings were encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are saving the format to `$bkgd_color{$color1}` other than to save some processing time but I suspect that is where your problem is. Try changing that section of your code to:

```
if ( $pattern == 1 ) {
    $format = $workbook->add_format(
        pattern => $pattern,
        bg_color => $color1,
        align => 'left',
        valign => 'top',
        text_wrap => $wrap,
        border => 1,
        color => $fontcolor,
        bold => $bold
    );
    $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value, $format);
}
```

Comment: My goal is simply to read in an existing spreadsheet, then create a new one just like the original, with the exception of altering the font color or fill color.

Comment: Ok, so you do not need the %bkgd_color hash then - have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @JHalbrook As it stands (i.e. saving the format in %bkgd_color), whenever $pattern = 1 and $color1 = 22 then the font color will always be set to whatever it is in the first cell that meets those conditions, regardless of what you set $fontcolor to be.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  I did notice that I was building the new worksheet one column at a time instead of one row at a time.  I modified to build one row at at time. Still, using your suggestion, I am seeing some cells missing the fill color, alignment, and font colors - even though my PROP debug file shows the correct values.  I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: The problem as i see it is not that you are building by row or column, but that you are saving a format in %bkgd_color and then applying that saved format to certain cells. You need to set a new format each time to those cells so you need to get rid of the %bkgd_color hash altogether.

Comment: Oh, yes, I agree and I did that.  See the new code above at the bottom of the original post.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See this new code removing the bgcolor logic.  Yet, the resulting spreadsheet is only partially formatted correctly:

```
my $parser          = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook_parse  = $parser->parse( $toxls );

my $worksheet_parse = $workbook_parse->Worksheet( $totab );
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_parse->col_range();
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_parse->row_range();

my $workbook   = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( $result_file );
my $worksheet  = $workbook->addworksheet( $totab );

$worksheet->set_column('A:A', 12);
$worksheet->set_column('C:C', 15);
$worksheet->set_column('D:D', 30);
$worksheet->set_column('E:E', 30);
$worksheet->set_column('F:F', 35);
$worksheet->set_column('G:G', 40);
$worksheet->set_column('I:I', 40);

for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

    # Return the cell object at $row and $col

    my $cell = $worksheet_parse->get_cell($row,$col);
    next unless $cell;

    my $value      = $cell->value();
    my $format     = $cell->get_format();

    my $pattern    = $format->{Fill}->[0];         
    my $color1     = $format->{Fill}->[1];
    my $color2     = $format->{Fill}->[2];
    my $wrap       = $format->{Wrap};       
    my $font       = $format->{Font};
    my $fontcolor  = $font->{Color};
    my $bold       = $font->{Bold};

    ## Change value if font color = black
    if ($fontcolor eq '32767') {
        $fontcolor = "8";
    }

    ##  Freeze after the header row

    if (index($value,"B\=baseline") > -1 || index($value,"B\=Baseline") > -1) {
       $worksheet->set_row($row, 150);
       $freezerow = $row + 1;
       $worksheet->freeze_panes($freezerow, 0); 
    }

    my $updformat = $workbook->add_format(
              pattern => $pattern,
              fg_color => $color1,
              bg_color => $color2,
              align => 'left',
              valign => 'top',
              text_wrap => $wrap,
              border => 1,
              color => $fontcolor,
              bold => $bold
    );

    $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value, $updformat);

    }  
}
```